# Chrome dev tools not showing on Mac

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools

Whenever I try to open the dev tools in Chrome, nothing seems to happen.

I've tried right-clicking the window and opening it from the drop down menu, opening it from the "more tools" menu found in the top right of the browser window, and the keyboard shortcut. I've also tried uninstalling and re-installing chrome.

Anyone have any ideas on how to fix this? Could possibly be opening outside of the window but I don't know how to check. I'm running mojave on Mac by the way, any help is appreciated.

Comment: I'm also having this problem on Movaje, with Chrome 80.0.3987.162. When I use the `Command+Option+J` shortcut, it highlights the View menu (so the shortcut at least seems to be triggering the correct action), but nothing happens.

Comment: I tried upgrading to Cantalina, but that didn't help. When I open the Chrome with `"/Applications/Google Chrome.app/Contents/MacOS/Google Chrome" --user-data-dir=/tmp/whatever`, the developer tools work.

Answer (score 1):

Deleting the local Chrome data and re-synching my browser fixed it for me. Specifically, I think this is the command that fixed it:

```
rm -rf ~/Library/Application Support/Google
```

But I followed [most of the steps here](https://crunchify.com/how-to-purge-all-your-google-chrome-user-data-on-mac-os-x/), so you can try them if the above command doesn't fix it.